# How do I fix this intelliJ issue?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crash, ide, font-size

In trying to change the intelliJ font from 13 to 12, I accident plugged in 1312, and instead of giving an error, IntelliJ actually made the font 1312 and it's freezing. I was not able to open preferences to change the font to 12. I deleted the application and re-downloaded it, still having problems. its still freezing and not even letting me access the preferences to change the font, I also thought the factory setting would be in place since I am redownloading it. not sure what to do...I have a project due tomorrow so im stressed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which OS you're running, so I can't provide super-specific guidelines here. But, if you can find Intellij's `editor.xml` file, it will contain a section like this:

```
<component name="DefaultFont">
  <option name="FONT_SIZE" value="1312" />
  <option name="FONT_FAMILY" value="Monaco" />
</component>
```

and all you should need to do is change that `1312` to `12`.

Here are some tips where you may find that file: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001219679-Where-does-IntelliJ-IDEA-store-the-editor-font-size-

If you're using [Settings Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-settings-repository.html) to store settings elsewhere, try editing that source instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the IDE UI font and not the editor font covered in the answer from Matt, look inside [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/options/other.xml` file instead for the lines like these:

```
  <component name="NotRoamableUiSettings">
    <option name="fontFace" value="Tahoma" />
    <option name="fontScale" value="1.0" />
    <option name="fontSize" value="13" />
  </component>
```